# Exporting Xcode's Code Coverage data

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7, xctest

Is there a way of accessing the data produced when you gather code coverage stats from your unit tests to text/command line or a way of exporting the data to another file format? Are there any third party libraries I can use? I am using Swift in Xcode 7.1.

Comment: The last time I was checking this for Swift, you could find the coverage data in project derived data but they were not made to be parsed outside Xcode - the format was not user friendly. I will check whether there is a feature request reported for Swift compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can check slather from the below link which is an open source tool to generate reports for Xcode's code coverage data. It generates reports in both xml and html formats

https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather

Comment: have you successfully exported report from Slather, I request you to share the steps for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fastlane or ruby gems you can use xcov to gather and display reports in HTML:

- https://github.com/fastlane-community/xcov
- https://rubygems.org/gems/xcov/versions/0.10

Comment: xcov doesn't work for me with Swift package projects. Just the note.

Comment: Not sure what is happening but I have several packages running xcov without an issue

Comment: No, before SPM I was used to having a workspace with two .xcodeproj: one for the framework and one for an example app. Old habits die hard and with that setup I have no issues.